# Php and Ajax not showing results from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I created proba.html file, getuser.php, database called: 'mobilni', and table called: 'imena'. What is wrong with code, it is not showing results from table, only blank?

proba.html code:

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>

<form>
<select name="okrug" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Okrug:</option>
  <option value="Raski">Raski</option>
  <option value="Banatski">Banatski</option>
  <option value="Backi">Backi</option>
  <option value="Beogradski">Beogradski</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
```

getuser.php code:

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mobilni');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"mobilni");
$sql="SELECT * FROM imena WHERE Okrug = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Ime</th>
<th>Okrug</th>
<th>Telefon</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Ime'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Okrug'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Telefon'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Please make some debugging effort - read logs, var_dump vars etc. No one will do it for you.

Comment: I tried that, but there is no any bug in logs.

Comment: Have you tested your query?, does it even return something?, try to debug and you'll narrow it down easily.

Comment: Try alert(str) in your ajax function. and echo $q; in your php, If you're getting these values then, check your sql query

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
```

Try this:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
```

See, if that helps.